# Websphere 8.5.5.2 + no object DCH for MIME type application/octet-stream Error

Tags: java, websphere, apache-axis, websphere-8

I have deployed my application in WAS 8.5.5.2. I have got below error. Any inputs from any one. Application uses AXIS2 1.5.4 version to get document renderer. During soap request to VRS machine, i am getting this error. 
 Any configuration required in WAS to resolve the same..

```
WSRenderer    I   Calling getRendererRef(): renderer Type=[OutInRenderer]
WSRenderer    I   Start: 
WSRenderer    E   Unable to perform rendering due to exception (org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type application/octet-stream)
WSRenderer    E   stacktrace=org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.flush(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:256)
                  org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:209)
```

Code:

```
Holder<String> errMsg = new Holder<String>();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(mRendererArgs.getData());
DataHandler idh = new DataHandler(bais, "application/octet-stream");
StringBuilder msg1= new StringBuilder();
renderReq.setInData(idh);
renderReq.setBstrFileName(mRendererArgs.getFileName());
renderReq.setPlBeginPage(plBeginPage.value);
renderReq.setPlEndPage(plEndPage.value);
renderReq.setPbstrImageType(pbstrImageType.value);
renderReq.setPpParams(new String[]{""});
//renderReq.setPpParams(new String[]{"zoomfactor","100","force8bits","0","conversiontype","1","height","800","width","1000","gettotalsubpages","0","quality","50"});
IMDVRSStub.RenderDocumentE renderReqE = new IMDVRSStub.RenderDocumentE();
renderReqE.setRenderDocument(renderReq);
ServiceClient sc = agentStub._getServiceClient();
Options options = sc.getOptions();
options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.ENABLE_MTOM, Constants.VALUE_TRUE);
sc.setOptions(options);
IMDVRSStub.RenderDocumentResponseE renderRespE = agentStub.renderDocument(renderReqE);
renderResp = renderRespE.getRenderDocumentResponse();
```